# My VBA isn't returning any errors but wont set the value of a cell in MS-Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I cannot figure out why my program will not do as I have intended it to do. I used very similar code to set the value in the rest of the program, but for this specific set, the code will not work.

```
public sub setValue(wrkBook as object, wrkSht as object)
    dim CurCell as object
    wrkSht = wrkbook.Sheets("TestSheet")
    Set curCell = wrkSht.Cells(4,1)
    CurCell.Value = "Test"
end sub
```

No errors are returned. I just simply does not set the value of cell(4,1) to "test". I'm using VBA from inside of Access

Comment: Is that an exact copy of your code? If so, I'd suggest you have an issue with `CurCell` / `curCell`. The editor would auto-amend these to be the same but if the capitalisation is not the same, this would suggest to me that there's something fishy going on.

Comment: Have you declared the variable `wrkShr` anywhere?

Comment: To add on to the above comment, `wrkShr <> wrkSht`.  I'd turn on `Option Explicit` to catch some of these kinds of errors.

Comment: Do you have `OnError Resume Next` further up the call tree? - The code you posted will error

Comment: Your latest edit won't run without errors either.  You'd have to have `Set wrkSht = wrkbook.Sheets("TestSheet")` instead of `wrkSht = wrkbook.Sheets("TestSheet")`  Any reason you're using objects implicitly rather than a more explicit reference like Workbook, Worksheet and Range?

Answer (score 4):

**wrkShr** is not the same as **wrkSht**:

```
Public Sub setValue(wrkBook As Object)
    Dim CurCell As Range, wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = wrkBook.Sheets("TestSheet")
    Set CurCell = wrkSht.Cells(4, 1)
    CurCell.Value = "Test"
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

In addition to the spelling, we have corrected the **Dim**'s and used **Set** to create the worksheet object.

Comment: Sorry, in retyping my code here I misspelled wrkSht. Unfortunately it is spelled correctly in my code..